# Reoccuring outliers after exclusion in R

Tags: r, statistics, boxplot, ggpubr

So I am analyzing some data regarding cell cultivation for my thesis and I am studying the cell morphology. Regarding the cell surface area I had some outliers that I excluded by simply subsetting. Below is some representative code:

```r
library(ggpubr)
random <- data.frame(x = c(sample(1:20, 40, replace = TRUE), 40, 30), 
                     y = c(sample(1:20, 40, replace = TRUE), 30, 52)) 
boxplot(random)

random2 <- subset(random, random < 21) 
boxplot(random2)
```

[image]
[image]

```r
compare_means(x~y, data=random2, 
              method="wilcox.test", 
              paired = FALSE, group.by = NULL, 
              ref.group = NULL) 

boxplotrandom <- ggboxplot(random2, x = "x", y = "y") 
boxplotrandom <- boxplotrandom + stat_compare_means() 
boxplotrandom
```

The boxplot after this (using `boxplot(random2)`) looks good, but when I perform the wilcoxon signed rank test and make a boxplot for the results using `ggboxplot() + stat_compare_means` I get outliers again. How can I get rid of those?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How did you call `ggboxplot` etc, can you provide that code as well? Furthermore (since you probably cannot share the data), can you create a small dataset that leads to the same behavior? That makes it easier to tell you what is going wrong here.

Comment: Yes I'd rather keep the data for myself, I have quickly made a dataframe. The final result is nothing like my data but the written code is exactly the same:   `random <- data.frame(x = c(sample(1:20, 40, replace = TRUE),40 ,30), y = c(sample(1:20, 40, replace = TRUE),30 ,52))
boxplot(random)
random2 = subset(random, random < 21)
boxplot(random2)
compare_means(x~y, data=random2, method="wilcox.test", paired = FALSE, group.by = NULL, ref.group = NULL)
boxplotrandom <- ggboxplot(random2, x = "x", y = "y")
boxplotrandom <- boxplotrandom+stat_compare_means()
boxplotrandom`

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I added the code (+ some images) to your question. I also think you meant `random2 <- subset(random, x < 21 & y < 21)` instead of `random < 21`, right? (Because otherwise it returns some weird results.) Anyway, the problem with the example data is that for me it seems to work just fine... The values above 20 are filtered ;)

Comment: Yes, in my data I handled the different parameters separately just like you did there with x<21 and y<21. The thing is that some days ago when I ran the code everything was fine... Thank you for your help!